# Where is wxThreadEvent defined?

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio-2008, wxwidgets

I have downloaded wxWidgets 2.8.1 for Windows (MSW).  The example in the [reference for wxThread](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_thread.html), shows the symbol `wxThreadEvent`.  My compiler, Visual Studio 2008, says that the symbol is undefined.

The sample for threading doesn't use `wxThreadEvent`.

I searched the `wxWidgets-2.8.1`, in a Cygwin terminal, using: 
`find /cygdrive/c/wxWidgets-2.8.1 -iname "*.h" -iname "*.[ch]pp" | xargs grep -n wxThreadEvent`
and no results were returned.

My question is, where is the symbol `wxThreadEvent` defined in the `wxWidgets` world?

Tools:  Visual Studio 2008, Windows Vista, wxWidgets 2.8.1 for MSW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation shows that [`wxThreadEvent`](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_thread_event.html) has been introduced in wxWidgets 2.9.0, so I suppose that's why you don't find it in 2.8.1.

Unless you have a really, *really* good reason to use 2.8.1, I'd like to recommend moving to 3.0.2, which still supports VC++ 2008 pretty well, as far as I know.

Comment: This is completely correct and I strongly suggest following the latter part of the advice. And if you absolutely need 2.8 (why?), at least use 2.8.12 and not the even more ancient 2.8.1.